# How do I set multiple AppSettings values using xWebConfigKeyValue?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to use the `xWebConfigKeyValue` resource of the DSC module `xWebAdministration` to set multiple values on our application's web.config file. This is an excerpt from our configuration with the main activities surrounding the web.config changes:

```
Configuration C4M
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $BuildDropLocation
    )

    Import-DscResource -Module xWebAdministration  

    Node $AllNodes.NodeName
    {
        $managementPortalInstallPath = 'c:\Company\ManagementPortal'
        File ManagementPortalContents
        {
            DestinationPath = $managementPortalInstallPath
            SourcePath = "$BuildDropLocation\ManagementPortal"
            Type = 'Directory'
            Recurse = $True
        }

        xWebConfigKeyValue RecaptchaPublicKey
        {
            WebsitePath = $managementPortalInstallPath
            ConfigSection = 'AppSettings'
            Key = 'recaptchaPublicKey'
            Value = $Node.RecaptchaPublicKey
            DependsOn = '[File]ManagementPortalContents'
        }

        xWebConfigKeyValue RecaptchaPrivateKey
        {
            WebsitePath = $managementPortalInstallPath
            ConfigSection = 'AppSettings'
            Key = 'recaptchaPrivateKey'
            Value = $Node.RecaptchaPrivateKey
            DependsOn = '[File]ManagementPortalContents'
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to run the configuration, I get the following error:

> Add-NodeKeys : The key properties combination
>   'C:\Company\ManagementPortal::AppSettings' is duplicated for keys
>   'WebsitePath,ConfigSection' of resource 'xWebConfigKeyValue' in node
>   'myNode'. Please make sure key properties are unique for each 
>   resource in a node. At line:160 char:9
>   +         Add-NodeKeys $keyValues $keyNames $keywordName
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DuplicateKeyInNode,Add-NodeKeys

After seeing the error, I took a look at the modules schema.mof file, and noticed that the appSettings key is not a key to the configuration at `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xWebAdministration\DSCResources\MSFT_xWebConfigKeyValue\MSFT_xWebConfigKeyValue.schema.mof`:

```
[ClassVersion("1.0.0.0"), FriendlyName("xWebConfigKeyValue")]
class MSFT_xWebConfigKeyValue : OMI_BaseResource
{
    [Key, Description("Path to website location(IIS or WebAdministration format)")] String WebsitePath;
    [Key, Description("Config Section to be update"), ValueMap{"AppSettings"}, Values{"AppSettings"}] String ConfigSection;
    [Write, ValueMap{"Present","Absent"}, Values{"Present","Absent"}] String Ensure;
    [Required, Description("Key for AppSettings")] String Key;
    [Write, Description("Value for AppSettings")] String Value;
    [Write, Description("If the given key value pair is for attribute, default is element")] Boolean IsAttribute;
};
```

Since only the site path and config section are keys, I can't have multiple instances of the resource pointing to the same appSettings block but with different appSetting keys. How can I configure multiple appSetting keys then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't configure two xWebConfigKeyValue resources in the same Configuration because, as you've found, the resource key only contains the WebsitePath and ConfigSection properties and doesn't discriminate on the Key property.

I think your immediate options are:

- Create a new cWebConfigKeyValue resource module based on xWebConfigKeyValue, and add the "Key" attribute to the "Key" property in the "cWebConfigKeyValue.schema.mof" to fix it yourself.

or

- Define the clashing resources in separate Configuration blocks. I've had to do this in a project that uses the xService resource.

Neither of these is a particularly good solution, but it might unblock you until a better fix comes along.

Comment: Do you happen to know _why_ it was designed that way? I mean... it is quite common to have more than one value on the `appSettings` section that needs to be configured. How would anyone base their implementations on this version of the resource? Anyways... I copied the original module/resource and renamed everything according to the suggested naming conventions (c prefix, company name instead of MSFT, new GUID, etc) and marked the `Key` property as a `[Key]` in the new schema.mof file. It is working as expected now.

Comment: I don't know why it was developed this way. To be honest, some of the DSC Wave X resources are quite disappointing and they don't seem to have been tested in real-world scenarios, so it's quite possibly just an oversight / bug.

Comment: This was fixed in [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/xWebAdministration/commit/45b92522d78b78743970d629c72fb13e2d4a8d7d#diff-0321ec2b010d299a431de5ecb7fd3ffe) commit. The "key" property has now the "key" attribute.